# How to match node key with the array of objects key in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have array of objects. I want to match a `groupName` key with the object I got.

The code that I'm using is:

`importedgroups.some(obj => obj.groupName === node.groupName)`

Here `importedgroups` is array of objects. It has objects with key name `groupName`. I have returned a object from some function. And when I try to check whether the returned object `groupName` is matching with the `importedgroups` then it is returning false.

`[{"groupName":"omnidocs_group","groupImportedAs":"Normal"},{"groupName":"omnidocs_group","groupImportedAs":"Normal","groupDistinguishName":"tmpDn"},{"groupName":"group_ouéñ","groupImportedAs":"Normal","groupDistinguishName":"tmpDn"}]`

But the object which I have has `groupName` exactly matching with the one object of `importedgroups` array.

How can I solve this?. Is there any alternative to that?

Comment: Please add the object that the function returns to the question.

Comment: What about the `importedgroups` array? Edit the question, and add both the object, and the array.

Comment: What is `node.groupName`? I assume `node` is a reference to a DOM-Element? Also add the respective HTML markup for that object please. If you have it in a data-attribute for example, you are accessing it wrong.

Comment: It should be `row.groupName`. But in function I'm using `node.groupName`

Comment: Actually it is TreeView of Material UI. That's why it is written as node

Comment: Either `node.groupName` isn't what you think it is, or there might be typo's/unprintable characters in there. [Otherwise it should work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/9uw8ehp3/).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]